# Custom sidebar in single.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I use this code to disply custom single.php pages (by category) in wordpress
and it works fine.

```
 get_header(); ?>

        <div id="container">
            <div id="content" role="main">

            <?php
              $post = $wp_query->post;

              if (in_category('4')) {
                  include(TEMPLATEPATH.'/loop-single-recept.php');
              } elseif (in_category('7')) {
                  include(TEMPLATEPATH.'/loop-single.php');
              } else {
                  include(TEMPLATEPATH.'/loop-single.php');
              }
                ?>


            </div><!-- #content -->
        </div><!-- #container -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

But I also want to disply custom sidebars in each single.php page.

Answer (score 2):

You can create multiple sidebar files and then call them using the (normally empty) argument in `<?php get_sidebar() ?>`

For example you create an alternative sidebar and call it sidebar-alternative.php and then call it using `<?php get_sidebar('alternative'); ?>`

So your code could be;

```
        <?php

          if (in_category('4')) {
              get_sidebar();
          } elseif (in_category('7')) {
              get_sidebar('alternative');
          } else {
              get_sidebar('alternative');
          }

         ?>
```

By the way I'm not making an issue of it, but you should think about accepting some of your answers as it will put people off answering - [Stackoverflow Answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes in_category() doesn't seem to work, I like to grab the category name from the $wp_query variable and include my own files:

```
if($wp_query->query['category_name'] == 'your-category-name-1') {

    include_once('sidebar-one.php');

} else if($wp_query->query['category_name'] == 'your-category-name-2') {

    include_once('sidebar-two.php');

} else {

    include_once('sidebar-three.php');

}
```